Cryptic crossword: London calling
This is a cryptic crossword.  All clues given are across clues, to be initially entered as numbered in the grid.  Coloured squares in the grid provide the down-element: each of five colours indicates that the letter that would go in that cell must be duplicated a prime number of rows below it (counting starts from the row below the entry, so 3 below row 1 is row 4).  Not all squares that can be coloured have been coloured.  Once solvers have completed the grid they should rearrange the answers appropriately.
All answers contain an extra letter which should be removed before entry.  In clue order these extra letters spell a phrase solvers may find useful.
To obtain the green tick solvers must complete the crossword, explain the clues, rearrange the answers and explain the rearrangement.

Across
1. Leaders of Durham educational association invite nominees for faculty president (4)
2. A paradise in quiet denial (4)
3. Hire car fixed up with more cunning (6)
4. Beer wars not about to be stirred up by drinksmaker (6)
5. Petty Officer left a new promotion for Lechia, once (6)
6. Russia's top two caught flourishing bear, perhaps? (6)
7. Cast away volleyball will soon strike one linesman's head (6)
8. Obvious new gain for US apple variety (7)
9. Noble gas flushing oxygen and secreting structure where Arthur was King (7)
10. Suomi find lane in disrepair (7)
11. Holy woman onboarding Colorado sect deserted Alba once (8)
12. Tank of boulder clay behind kirk (9)
13. Old farmer keeps heads of moose, wolf and caribou next to… duck? (9)
14. Teenage sham unraveled at site of betrayal? (10)
15. Capture original enthusiasm first on Aotearoa (11)
16. Thirty hell glades misrepresented pleasures of the world (15)
As the colours are important: labelling the columns as A-P and the rows as 1-16, the coloured cells are:
BLACK:  D1, G1
RED:    D3, H3, M10, F11, L12
WHITE:  K5 ,L5, I6, I9, J9, J11
BLUE:   G4, G11, M11,  E12, K13, L13, D14, E14
YELLOW: G3
PINK:   K10
GREEN:  J5
ORANGE: H4

The solved clues (in the usual cryptic annotation style, with extra letters marked by [[double brackets]]):

 1. DEA[[I]]N (inits)
 2. _E[[T]]DEN_
 3. ARCHER[[I]]*
 4. BREWER(-a)[[S]]*
 5. PO + L + AN + [[A]]D
 6. RU_ + [[C]] + PERT
 7. WIL(-l) SO[[O]]N
 8. BALD + [[N]] + WIN
 9. [[N]]E(-o)N + GLAND
 10. FINLAND[[E]]*
 11. S(CO)T + [[C]]LAN+D
 12. CHURCH+[[T]]ILL
 13. M[[W]]AC (inits) + DONALD
 14. GETHSEMANE[[A]]*
 15. (NEW+ZEAL)+[[L]]AND
 16. EARTHLY DELIGHTS[[L]]*

These do indeed fit into the grid as given:

 
 For the prime numbers: blue is 2, red is 3, white is 5, black is 7, and yellow is 11. Mixes of these colors indicate letters in both of the positions: orange is red+yellow, pink is red+white, and green is blue+yellow.

The extra letters

 spell IT IS A CONNECT WALL. As suggested, we can solve an Only-Connect-style connecting wall with these sixteen answers as the entries.

The 'rearrangement' is

 the following four categories.

 "Garden of ___": EDEN, ENGLAND, GETHSEMANE, EARTHLY DELIGHTS
 Countries ending in "Land": POLAND, FINLAND, SCOTLAND, NEW ZEALAND (with ENGLAND being a red herring)
 Streets in Soho, London: DEAN, ARCHER, BREWER, RUPERT (with POLAND being a red herring)
 Prime ministers: WILSON, BALDWIN, CHURCHILL, MACDONALD (with EDEN being a red herring)


I think your missing C is just the C from 'caught' (cricket notation)

Well done!  Stiv is right, the C is from Caught, and one definition of pert, given in Chambers, is flourishing.  The holy woman was just intended to clue Saint; Chambers gives "Ste -- Sainte" as French so I think I'd be compelled to clue it as French holy woman in that case.  (If it matters, I had St Margaret of Scotland in mind when constructing the clue originally.)

@Stiv Ahh, a cultural reference I never would've gotten. I had enough trouble with this puzzle full of Britishisms already! Thanks for pointing it out.
